# Multiple Array keys in WordPress get_posts Function

Tags: php, wordpress

small question. I need to specify multiple meta keys and values in wordpress [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, never mind, found my solution in the documentation. If someone needs it,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured',
            'value' => 'yes',
        )
    )
 );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```